# Consulta síncrona no SQLite usando Ionic

Tags: sqlite, angular, ionic2, typescript

Tenho a seguinte função abaixo:

```
public requisicaoXPTA() {
  this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM tbl_xpta",
      []).then((data) => {
      // o resultado retorna aqu na variável data

      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);    
  });
}
```

Qndo vou usar essa função faço desta forma:

```
this.requisicaoXPTA();
this.atualizar();
```

Na maioria das vezes, a função `atualizar()` é executada antes da `requisicaoXPTA()`. Gostaria executar a função `atualizar()` depois de ter realizado a requisição na tabela. Qual melhor forma de fazer isso de forma síncrona?

Comment: Já tentou usar o async e await?

Comment: Um chute, que tal adicionar o `this.atualizar` dentro do `.then`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento se usar `this.atualizar` dentro do `.then` funciona, porém gostaria adicionar o `requisicaoXPTA` em um outro arquivo(classe), que não seja onde o `this.atualizar` se encontra. Então por esse motivo eu queria receber primeiro o resultado da função para depois prosseguir para atualização.

Comment: @DiegoAugusto não tentei não. Vou dar uma olhada pra ver como funciona isso ai. Valeu a dica.

Comment: @acklay vou colocar um exemplo nas respostas.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode passar um *callback* pra ser executado depois da requisição, assim:

```
public requisicaoXPTA(callback) {
  this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM tbl_xpta", []).then((data) => {
    callback();
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);    
  });
}
```

O uso ficaria assim

```
this.requisicaoXPTA(this.atualizar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Poderia usar a ideia do @LINQ, mas tornado o callback opicional:

```
public requisicaoXPTA(callback) {
  this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM tbl_xpta", []).then((data) => {
    if (callback) callback(data);
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);    
  });
}
```

No momento que vai necessitar do `this.atualiza` usaria assim:

```
requisicaoXPTA(this.atualiza);
```

Quando não for usar basta omitir:

```
requisicaoXPTA();
```

Ou poderia usar um parâmetro para dizer quando deve ou não atualizar, por exemplo:

```
public requisicaoXPTA(refresh) {

  this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM tbl_xpta", []).then((data) => {
    if (refresh) this.atualiza(data);
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);    
  });
}
```

Não lembro se `this` funciona dentro do `=> {}` devido ao escopo, se não der faça assim:

```
public requisicaoXPTA(refresh) {
  var callback = refresh ? this.atualiza : false;

  this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM tbl_xpta", []).then((data) => {
    if (callback) callback();
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);    
  });
}
```

Comment: Opa! Blz bro?! Mas o que estou dizendo é que o método `requisicaoXPTA` e atualiza estão em classes diferentes. Por isso eu disse que não queria usar o método `this.atualiza` dentro do `requisicaoXPTA`. Na prática o `requisicaoXPTA` deveria me retornando uma lista de "valores". Algo nesse sentido: `let values = this.requisicaoXPTA();` Pra depois eu poder usar essa `values` dentro de `this.atualiza()`;

Comment: @acklay editei o código, veja se faz sentido pra ti agora, passei data como argumento

Comment: Seu primeiro exemplo está fazendo mais sentido pra mim. Amanha vou testar e te falo. Só não tenho certeza se eu colocando em sequência o método `atualiza` continuará sendo executado antes do método `requisicaoXPTA`. Você acha que resolve assim então?!

Comment: O problema principal seria porque o método `executeSql` é assíncrono. Por isso a dificuldade.

Comment: se eu usar somente  `let values = this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM tbl_xpta", []);` funciona em partes, porém não conseguir abstrair o objeto `data` no retorno desta forma. =/

Comment: Enfim, amanhã vou fazer uns testes e te falo. Vlw

Comment: @acklay mas assíncrono é lindo, assíncrono é vida, assíncrono provê uma UX mais saudável :)

Comment: Eu sei, mas não resolve meu problema agora! heheh... Acho que estou fazendo algo errado. ehuheuhe

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [async e await](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/async-await.html) que está presente desde o `typeScript 2.1`.

Exemplo:

```
public async requisicaoXPTA() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM tbl_xpta",
        []).then((data) => {
          resolve(data);
        }, (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    })
}
```

Repare que estou resolvendo a promise para que consigamos pegar o resultado fora da mesma. Feito isso você pode chamar sua função:

```
let resultado = await this.requisicaoXPTA();
```

Com o `await` a promisse será resolvida e 'cursor' ficará travado nessa função até que a mesma esteja completa. Em seguida você pode chamar sua outra função:

```
let resultado = await this.requisicaoXPTA();
console.log(resultado);
this.atualizar();
```